# TensorflowJS Cannot read property 'backend' of undefined in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, node-modules, tensorflow.js

I've seen the questions related to this issue but I cannot make it work even with the tfjs vanilla module.

this are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl": "^4.6.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-core": "^4.6.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^4.6.0",
    "canvas": "^2.11.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "jsdom": "^21.1.2",
    "node-cmd": "^5.0.0",
    "node-gyp": "^9.3.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "png-js": "^1.0.0",
    "xml-js": "^1.6.11"
}
```

First I load de modules:

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl');
```

Then I load the model:

```
const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(path);
```

Then I pre-process the image:

```
const batched = tf.tidy(() => {
        const imageTensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(cnv);
        return (
          imageTensor
            //   .transpose([0, 1, 2])
            //.resizeBilinear([width, height])
            .resizeBilinear([width, height])
            .expandDims(0)
            .toInt()
        );
});
```

And finally call to model.executeAsync:

```
return model.executeAsync(batched,["StatefulPartitionedCall/Postprocessor/Slice","StatefulPartitionedCall/Postprocessor/ExpandDims_1"]).then(function (result){
    console.log("flag 0");
} //It never reaches the console log.
```

The exception:

```
@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:4519
    var srcBackend = info.backend;
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'backend')
    at Engine.moveData (\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:4519:31)
    at DataStorage.get (\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:230:28)
    at NodeJSKernelBackend.getInputTensorIds (\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\nodejs_kernel_backend.js:169:43)
    at NodeJSKernelBackend.executeSingleOutput (\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\nodejs_kernel_backend.js:216:73)
    at Object.kernelFunc (\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\kernels\Reshape.js:34:27)
    at kernelFunc (\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:4704:32)
    at \node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:4764:27
    at Engine.scopedRun (\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:4569:23)
    at Engine.runKernelFunc (\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:4760:14)
    at Engine.runKernel (\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:4633:21)
```

I'm running on windows with an anaconda enviroment:
Python 2.7 (as recomended by tensorflowjs)
Node.js v18.15.0

I've tried every solution that I've found, I don't know what am I doing wrong.

I think is a bug:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/7706

Answer (score 0):

Try to set:
`await tf.setBackend('webgl') // Or 'wasm'` before running `model.execAsync()`. It worked for me.

In your code write:

```js
const predict = async (batched) => {
    await tf.setBackend('webgl'); // Or 'wasm'
    return model.executeAsync(batched, 
["StatefulPartitionedCall/Postprocessor/Slice","StatefulPartitionedCall/Postprocessor/ExpandDims_1"]).then(function (result){
    console.log("flag 0");
} //It should reach the flag now
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've already tried that, forgot to mention. I just downgraded to 3.6 and now it's working